# quote back-tick quote...enclosed in back-ticks

Tags: markdown, backticks

I have a code snippit like:

```
console.log('`', '...')
```

The first argument to `log` here is *quote*, *back-tick*, *quote*.

I would like to embed this in a sentence in a markdown document like:

```
this code `code` is foo.
```

But, when I try this:

```
this code `console.log('`', '...')` is foo.
```

it's not coming out right because of the nested back-tick characters.

Any advice on how to correctly escape the back-ticks?

Comment: Can you show us your desired output at least in terms of chracters?  I am not seeing a problem here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The goal here is to make the code snippit (which includes the ` character) appear in a code block. If you enter my attempt above into a tool like http://dillinger.io/ you'll see that the formatting is messed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double backticks around the code block:

```
``console.log('`', '...')``
```

This has been tested on [dillinger.io](http://dillinger.io/) and it appears to be working.